# React Dependent from API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I am searching a lot about this topic but can’t seem to find a answer that clarifies me.
I am trying to make my first react app. I have started with create react app to understand the basics and then moved my app to server side rendering. As I was developing I got in a question. How can I fetch some data from my API before the app gives a answer (server side) so I can put some stuff in there that I really need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an ajax request to pull the data from API and set that to the `state` variable of react. So that the state variable will be used during render. You could define a method for this and, you can call that method from `componentDidMount()` to set the values to the state variable.

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data : []};
    },
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
    handleCommentSubmit: function(comment){
        var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
         $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer(), this.props.pollInterval);
    },
    render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='commentBox'>
        <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
                <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

In the above code sample, I wrote a method `loadCommentsFromServer()` specifically to pull data from an API. And I call that from `componentDidMount()` and stored the output from API into state variable. And, I used the state variable during render.

***Note: The above code sample may not work on its own. Since, it's dependencies are not resolved.***